# Разделить строку на подстроки

Tags: php

Есть txt файл, содержащий информацию в строках. Примерно вот:

```
00915DU000D1IH5UP~1~6000037024~01~~000~22617962291~23510372601~44000.00~44000.00~00074~23510000900335086001~03.10.2011~00634~
```

И нужно каждую стоку разбить в массивы ориентир `(~)! explode("~",$stroka);`, но тут бывает `2(~~)`. Как мне это сделать, помогите!

Comment: А что делать в случае с `~~` ?

Comment: Хм... А зачем вам что-то делать с ~~? Возможно, это пустое значение какого-то параметра, и, если, его пропустить, могут возникнуть проблемы при разборе массива.

Comment: ето разделители между цифрами! значение не имеют! хочется что то вроде : 
array[0]=>1212122
      [1]=>232455  ну вы поняли

Comment: Какой массив должен получится из строки `6000037024~01~~000~22617962291`?

Comment: если две ~~ то между ними должна быть пустая ячейка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Способ первый:

```
preg_match_all('/[^~]+/',$string,$matches);
```

//$matches[0] содержит нужные элементы.

Comment: здесь тоже почему то ошибка:
Warning: preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in

Comment: Ну $string - это ваша строка. $matches - пустая переменная, в которую оно сложит ответы. А вы как применяете?

Comment: preg_match_all('/[^~]+/',$stroka,$matches);

Comment: надо в цикле ??

Comment: Ну, если у вас это массив строк - да. explode тоже с массивами не очень работает, вроде как.

Answer (score 2):

```
explode("~", preg_replace("/~{2,}/", "~", $stroka))
```

Comment: только заменять оно должно не на пустую строку, а на ~ иначе двойные превратятся не в одинарные, а исчезнут вообще

Comment: исчезло всё)

Comment: Странно у меня вот что получается:

    var_dump(explode("~", preg_replace("/~{2,}/", "", "00915DU000D1IH5UP~1~6000037024~01~~000~22617962291")));

Получаем:

    array(5) {
      [0]=>
      string(17) "00915DU000D1IH5UP"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "1"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "6000037024"
      [3]=>
      string(5) "01000"
      [4]=>
      string(11) "22617962291"
    }

Comment: Спосибо большое! у вас всё верно! это я тут ошибся) 
а если в строке ещё может быть и пробел в место одного ~
00915DU000D1IH5UP~1~6000037024~01~~000 22617962291 как мне сделать так что бы если будет пробел то нужно сделать другое??

Comment: @chernomyrdin, [3] неверно. Там должно быть [3]=>01, [4]=>000, а у вас оно слиплось. Про что я и говорил.

Comment: Понял, тогда:

    explode("~", preg_replace("/~{2,}/", "~", "00915DU000D1IH5UP~1~6000037024~01~~000~22617962291"))

Answer (score 2):

```
print_r(preg_split('/~+/', $str));
```

Comment: тут говорит что параметров не хватает

Comment: `php -r '$str="00915DU000D1IH5UP~1~6000037024~01~~000~22617962291"; print_r(preg_split("/~+/", $str));'
    Array
    (
        [0] => 00915DU000D1IH5UP
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 6000037024
        [3] => 01
        [4] => 000
        [5] => 22617962291
    )
`

а у меня всё ок...

Answer (score 0):

Спосибо большое! у вас всё верно! это я тут ошибся) а если в строке ещё может быть и пробел в место одного ~ 00915DU000D1IH5UP~1~6000037024~01~~000 22617962291 как мне сделать так что бы если будет пробел то нужно сделать другое??

Comment: НЕНАВИЖУ ЭТОТ РЕДАКТОР!!!

    preg_match_all('/[^~\s]+/',$string,$matches); //если пробел - тоже разделитель

О, так заработало. =)

Comment: не понел на счёт пробела! смотрите идут цифры  00915DU000D1IH5UP~1~6000037024~01~~000 22617962291
если вот пробел будет то мне нужно совсем другое делать! помогите плизз

Comment: Ребят здесь если две ~~ то это пустое поле что делать помогите!!!! пусть масив пустым останестя! напишите плизз

Comment: Если совсем другое, используйте другое регулярное выражение. =)
`\s` - пробел.

Если ~~ - пустое поле, то достаточно explode. Он 123~456~~789 превратит в
array(123,456,'',789);

Comment: да! спосибо большое ребят! explode и всё)

Comment: `*`**застрелился**`*`